# Toggle class on and off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some links on a page.  When the metro link is clicked the state links should be disabled.  When the county link is clicked it then should renable the links.  Using the add and remove class via jquery worked but only one time.  I moved on to using the toggle class and both the county and metro link can toggle the links off and on.  I create a fiddle also for better explanation.

http://jsfiddle.net/8u4jw72h/

here is the java script

```
function stateSelection(evt) {       
app.map.on("load", function () {

    $('.state-link').on('click', function () {

        switch (params.region_code) {
            case 9:
                zoomTo = conn;
                break;
            case 23:
                zoomTo = maine;
                break;
            case 25:
                zoomTo = mass;
                break;
            case 44:
                zoomTo = rhode;
                break;
        }
        app.map.centerAndZoom(zoomTo, 8);
        $('#btnModelReset').click();           

    });
    if (app.map.getZoom() <= 7) {            
        app.map.graphics.clear();
    }

    dojo.connect(dojo.byId('ctyRegion'), 'onclick', function () {
        app.map.centerAndZoom(home, 7);            
        enable();
    });
    dojo.connect(dojo.byId('msaRegion'), 'onclick', function () {
        app.map.centerAndZoom(home, 7);                                  
        disable();                       
    });

});//end load  
}//end state selection

function disable() {
$(".state-link").toggleClass('disableClass');
}
function enable() {
$(".state-link").toggleClass('enableClass');
}
```

and here is the css

```
a {
color: #333;
outline: none;
padding-left: 3px;
padding-right: 3px;
text-decoration: underline;
}

a:link, a:visited,
a:active, a:hover {
    color: #333;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: #c7d1d6;
}

.disableClass{
pointer-events:none;
text-decoration:none;
opacity: 0.4;
cursor:default;
}

.enableClass{
color: #333;
outline: none;
padding-left: 3px;
padding-right: 3px;
text-decoration: underline;    
opacity:1;
pointer-events:all;
cursor:default;
}
```

Comment: So do not toggle, add and remove instead.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or simply use only one class and the snippet below

```
$('#msaRegion').click(function () {
    $(".state-link").addClass('disableClass');
});
$('#ctyRegion').click(function () {
    $(".state-link").removeClass('disableClass');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8u4jw72h/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You forget remove the old class, try:

```
$('#msaRegion').click(function () {
    $(".state-link").removeClass('enableClass').addClass('disableClass');
});
$('#ctyRegion').click(function () {
    $(".state-link").removeClassClass('disableClass').addClass('enableClass');
});
```